# Changing Values in a Point

Tags: java, swing, awt, point

```
Point p1 = new Point(100, 100);
Point p2 = new Point(300, 100);
Point p3 = new Point(110, 100);
int x3 = 310;
Point p4 = new Point(100, 100);
static JFrame start = new JFrame("Start");

if(p3.x >= start.getWidth()-90)
{
    p3.x = (int) (p1.getX()+10);
    p3.setLocation(p3.x, p3.y);
    repaint();
}

if(key == KeyEvent.VK_S && !paused)
{
    p1.y++;
    p4.y++;
    p1.setLocation(p1.x, p1.y);
    test1.setBounds(new Rectangle(p1, new Dimension(64, 64)));
    repaint();
    sound.soundPlay(3);
}
```

In this, the x value of point p3 is supposed to be the same as the value of p1.getX()+10. The value is changed to 100+10, but I have changed 100 to a different value in the second block. How do I update p1 in the first block to match the p1 in the second block?

Comment: *"How do I update p1 in the first block to match the p1 in the second block?"*  Move it before the first block, or give it the ability to bend time?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Is there an *open-source* API available to *bend time*? I would be really interested :D

Comment: @Sujay Sure, just visit 2046 to get a copy.  ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to my question. This is my new code:

```
Point p1 = new Point(100, 100);
Point p2 = new Point(300, 100);
Point p3 = new Point(110, 100);
Point p5 = new Point(310, 100);
Point p4 = new Point(90, 100);
static JFrame start = new JFrame("Start");

if(p3.x >= start.getWidth()-90)
{
    p3.x = start.getWidth()-70;
    p3.x = (int) (p1.getX()+10);
    p3.setLocation(p3.x, p3.y);
}

if(key == KeyEvent.VK_S && !paintingFBR && !paused)
{
    p1.y++;
    p3.y++;
    test1.setLocation(p1);
    test3.setLocation(p3);
}
```

Comment: Just adding new code doesn't tell us what the problem was, or why this fixed it.